# Thymeleaf th:src with variables in server-relative url

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am having a problem figuring out the syntax to generate a server-relative URL with variable substitution.

If I do this:

```
<img th:src="@{~'/puzzles/'+${category.getDirName()}+'/'+${category.getRandomPuzzleName()}+'.png'}"/>
```

Thymeleaf outputs the code into the page source:

```
<img src="~&#39;/puzzles/&#39;+${category.getDirName()}+&#39;/&#39;+${category.getRandomPuzzleName()}+&#39;.png&#39;"/>
```

If I remove the tilde (So it is now a context-relative url):

```
<img th:src="@{'/puzzles/'+${category.getDirName()}+'/'+${category.getRandomPuzzleName()}+'.png'}"/>
```

Thymeleaf interprets the variables and gives me this output:

```
<img src="/www/puzzles/3DMathPuzzles-Cube-555/3DMathPuzzle-Cube-555-00011-5.png"/>
```

But, of course the URL is not what I want because it has the '/www' context.

I want the tag to be this:

```
<img src="/puzzles/3DMathPuzzles-Cube-555/3DMathPuzzle-Cube-555-00011-5.png"/>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What is the HTML you _do_ want to generate? Can you add that to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used server-relative URLs with Thymeleaf, but if I understand the documentation correctly, the `~` needs to be part of the string:

```
<img th:src="@{'~/puzzles/'+${category.getDirName()}+'/'+${category.getRandomPuzzleName()}+'.png'}"/>
```

If that doesn't work, try the URL placeholder syntax:

```
<img th:src="@{~/puzzles/{dir}/{name}.png(dir=${category.getDirName()}, name=${category.getRandomPuzzleName()})}"/>
```

Comment: Adding the tilde as part of the string worked, thank you!  That was counter-intuitive to me since I assumed Thymeleaf would take it as a literal and not process it.